# UIControl actions based on mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have over 100 IBActions in my app and I already implemented all the actions. Now the issue is my app can run two modes (called client and server modes) with the same UI. One way to update the app to support the two modes is:

```
@IBAction button_n_Action(_ sender:Any?) {

 if self.mode == server {
    // Server code
 } else {
    // Client code
 }

}
```

Only problem is n varies from 1 to 100, which to me sounds ugly, complex, repetitive code. Is there a cleaner, better, or clever way in Swift/XCode that I can easily separate client & server code?

Comment: I would try to subclass the view controller to override everything. Not exactly sure how well that works in practice...

Comment: Do you have actions spread ed inside the app or in 1 activity ?

Comment: Actions are spread in the same view controller. I have an object to fetch most data to display. In the case of client, the data object is fetched from server.

Comment: see if this would fit with a table and if so then the 2 issues will be solved

Comment: What do you mean by table? I have a custom UI defined that I don't want to change.

Comment: @Max I think subclassing view controller is good, only thing is the root view controller will need to be changed in this case the moment I set the mode to client in settings.